# Commutator of $B$, $C$ vanishes if $A$, $B$, $C$, $AB$, $AC$ are Hermitian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator, linear-algebra

> Suppose 3 operators $A$, $B$, $C$ are Hermitian operators. Assume $A$ has a non-degenerate spectrum, and $AB$ and $AC$ are also Hermitian. Show that $$[B,C] = 0$$

From the conditions $A$, $B$, $C$, $AB$ and $AC$ are Hermitian operators, one can derive that $$[A,B]=[A,C]=0$$
How can one proceed to show that $[B,C]=0$?

Comment: Note that $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$. Think: how does that look if $A, B$ and $AB$ are Hermitian? what does that tell us?

Comment: I know that gives us $[A,B]=0$, same argument gives $[A,C]=0$, but how do we relate this to [B,C]?

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough. You can show that $[A, BC]=0$. This, together with the fact that $A$ is non degenerate, should allow you to show that $BC$ is also hermitian.

Comment: This is where I get unsure, I tried to write $A=\sum_i a_i|a_i><a_i|$, with $a_i \neq a_j$. But I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Great, so eigenvectors are orthogonal, $A=\sum_i a_i ~|i\rangle\langle i|$, $B=\sum_i b_i ~|i\rangle\langle i|$, and $C=\sum_i c_i ~|i\rangle\langle i|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there. If $A$ commutes with $B$ it means that they can be diagonalized simultaneously. Now use the fact the the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-degenerate. This means that also $B$ is diagonal in the same basis. Repeat with $C$ and you are done.